# How to set camera to view the whole floorplan?

Tags: camera

[image]My floorplan units are set to inches. I added a camera to view from the top as shown but when I hit (0) for camera view, I have a feeling it is view a small portion with no detail in it. I zoomed all the way out and played with camera scale but camera view shows nothing. Any advise? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your camera clipping end value is too small. Try setting it to 15' or more.

The floor plan is 14' 8.58" away from the camera, but the camera end clip value is 8' 4". This means that no objects further than 8' 4" away from the camera will be displayed in the camera view.

[image]

Also, make sure that the camera clipping start is smaller than the distance between the object and the camera, for the same reason.

Comment: Ah! That's what S: and End: mean! Thank you.